# Android: Cropping an image to specific size

Tags: android, image, image-processing, camera, crop

My intention is to have the user pick an image from the gallery, then have a cropping activity come up. However, I need the rectangle that defines the cropping mask to be locked to a certain dimension and then the user simply repositions it to display a portion of an image.

Any ideas on how this would be done?

Thanks

-T

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758425/how-to-set-the-output-image-use-com-android-camera-action-crop/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null)
            .setType("image/*")
            .putExtra("crop", "true")
            .putExtra("aspectX", width)
            .putExtra("aspectY", height)
            .putExtra("outputX", width)
            .putExtra("outputY", height)
            .putExtra("scale", true)
            .putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true)
            .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f))
            .putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
```

Comment: are you sure ..? i am not getting with this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a custom `ImageView` class to achieve zooming and panning of an image and can have a fixed rectangle `image(transparent)` overlaying on this image. And can create sub-bitmap of that bitmap. and save it in a file.

```
createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

This method is used to create a sub-bitmap.

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

After achieving zooming and panning, I am not sure if `createBitmap` can create sub-bitmap from the visible portion of the image(i.e. part of image wont be visible on the screen when it is zoomed), So try getting the `drawingCache()` from `imageView` and create sub-bitmap for the same.

Comment: I can give you custom image class with zooming and panning if you want.

Comment: how would I grab the sub-bitmap. That sounds like black magic. -TDK

Comment: That custom class would help tremendously. :)

Comment: yea. It does everything for you.

Comment: Ah I see! You would use the positioning of the rectangle in space to define the coordinates! Killer!

Comment: Where can I find the view for this?

Comment: Yes :) THe custom image view.

Comment: I have added a URL in the answer